# How to map with underscore but without falsy values added to the result

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I have  an array of objects where I wanna only save a sub object when it pass a condition. At the moment I first use `map` and then `filter` with the result:

```
   var a = _.filter(
    _.map(activities.toJSON(), function (activity) {
    if (activity.verb !== 'test') {
      return activity.object;
    }
  }), function(b){return b;});
```

This seems a bit odd. Is there a better way to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any time you start doing things like `_.f(_.g(...))`, you should think about using [`_.chain`](http://underscorejs.org/#chain). You could do something like this:

```
var a = _.chain(activities.toJSON())
         .select(function(a) { return a.verb !== 'test' })
         .map(function(a) { return a.object })
         .value();
```

I've also adjusted your logic to simplify things, there's no need to do the same test twice. You can make this sort of thing quite readable if you put your functions into variables:

```
var not_tests   = function(a) { return a.verb !== 'test' };
var extract_obj = function(a) { return a.object };
var results     = _.chain(activities.toJSON())
                   .select(not_tests)
                   .map(extract_obj)
                   .value();
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/EQfuH/

There will be a fair bit of copying with this approach so you might want to just go old-school and use a loop:

```
var json = activities.toJSON();
var a    = [ ];
for(var i = 0; i < json.length; ++i)
    if(json[i].verb !== 'test')
        a.push(json[i].object);
```

There's nothing at all wrong with loops in JavaScript.

Comment: After all the plain JavaScript solution seems to be the clearest one.

Comment: @AndreasKöberle: True, I'd probably only bother with the Underscore stuff if there were more steps to the logic or if the functions used in the steps depended on something else (i.e. sometimes you wanted `not_tests` and sometimes `not_pancakes`).

Answer (score 4):

You can try [#reduce](http://underscorejs.org/#reduce)

```
_.reduce(activities.toJSON(), function(accum, activity){
  if (activity.verb !== 'test')
    accum.push(activity.object);
  return accum;
}, []);
```

[**Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/tHjeW/)

Comment: Sorry but this doesn't work. On the second call of the reduce function accum is 1 and so has no method `push`

Comment: I didn't test the code. I will take a look. This should work.

Comment: It should work when you return `accum` in any case, not `accum.push`. Cause push returns the new length of the array.

Comment: but after all it seems a simple `each` loop will to the same without the need of return something from the inner function

Comment: I think `reduce` is better than creating an array then iterating over your collection and pushing onto the array . `reduce` does it all at once.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for [`_.compact()`](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/#compact):

```
var a = _.compact(
    _.map(activities.toJSON(), function (activity) {
    if (activity.verb !== 'test') {
      return activity.object;
    }
  }));
```

Another approach, which I think is a bit nice semantically, is to filter out the ones you don't want, then use `_.pluck`:

```
var a = _.filter(activities.toJSON(), function (activity) {
    return activity.verb !== 'test';
}).pluck('object');
```

Comment: These would be even nicer with `_.chain()` or perhaps I'm inordinately fond of `_.chain`.

Comment: I usually avoid `_.chain()` unless I have > 2 underscore calls in a row - otherwise adding both `.chain()` and `.value()` seems like too much bloat.